# `react-hover` npm package not in production build but working fine in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to make use of the npm package [`react-hover`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hover) (here's the [github link](https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover)) in my project and when I develop locally in dev build it works just fine. When I run the `npm run build` command and serve the production version the components I want to show in the `<ReactHover>` object don't render on the page.

I started the project using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files) I serve the production version locally using the npm package `serve`.

I will share all the files of my project since it's nothing spectacular, here are [all files on a public repo](https://github.com/qxh5696/dummy-react-project).

I haven't really been able to find this issue anywhere else so any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CSS to do that.
Define two divs, one with id="hover-selector-parent" and another with id="hover-selector-child".

Then configure your CSS file to handle the event -

```
#hover-selector-parent:hover~#hover-selector-child{
  display:block;
}

#hover-selector-child{
  display: none;
}
```